# Well formed Http Request

Tags: callout, httprequest

I'm trying to make a callout to AWS S3 [Put Object - Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) from APEX code, the request must be something like:

```
PUT /destinationObject HTTP/1.1
Host: destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /source_bucket/sourceObject
Authorization: authorization string
Date: date
```

Right now I have something like (Using Salesforce's HttpRequest class):

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('PUT');
request.setEndpoint('https://destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com');
request.setHeader('x-amz-copy-source', '/source_bucket/sourceObject');
request.setHeader('Authorization', authorization);
```

Which gives me:

```
PUT    HTTP/1.1
Host: destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /source_bucket/sourceObject
Authorization: authorization string
```

I could not understand how should/can I build the `/destinationObject` part of the request. How can I build this?